# GitLab CI Yocto Build - How to use SSTATE and DL_DIR

Tags: gitlab, yocto, gitlab-ci-runner, bitbake

How to configure GitLab CI to store the `SSTATE_DIR` and the `DL_DIR` between several jobs? Currently, bitbake rebuilds the complete project every time, which is very time consuming. So i would like to use the sstage again. I tried caching, but building time increases effectively, due to the big zip/unzip overhead.

I don't even need a shared sstate between several projects, just a method to store the output between jobs.

I'm using Gitlab 11.2.3 with a shell executor as runner.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 11.10, [GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-clean-flags) was added, which could be used to achieve what you want to do with the shell executor.

For completeness: when using the docker executor, this can be achieved by using docker volumes, which are persistent across builds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using one runner for this, you could potentially use `GIT_STRATEGY: none`, which would re-use the project workspace for the following job; [relevant documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy). However, this wouldn't be extremely accurate in case you have multiple jobs running which requires the runner, as it could dilute the repository, if jobs are started from across different pipelines.

Another way, if you're still using one runner, is you could just copy the directories out and back into the job you require.

Otherwise, you may potentially be out of luck, and have to wait for the [sticky runners](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29447) issue.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, specified `GIT_STRAGETY: none`. It was a little bit tricky, because you have to set up the pull commands at your own. There's an issue on GitLab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/196 which seems to do the trick easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse a shared-state cache between jobs simply as follows:

Specify the path to the sstate-cache directory in the `.yml` file of your
gitlab-ci pipeline. An example fragment from one of mine:

**myrepo.yml**

```
stages:
  ...
  ...

variables:
  ...
  TCM_MACHINE: buzby2
  ...
  SSTATE_CACHE: /sstate-cache/$TCM_MACHINE/PLAT3/
  PURGE_SSTATE_CACHE: N
  ...
```

In my case `/sstate-cache/$TCM_MACHINE/PLAT3/` is a directory in the docker container
that runs the build. This path is mounted in the docker container from a
permanent sstate cache directory on the build-server's filesystem, `/var/bitbake/sstate-cache/<machine-id>/PLAT3`.

`PURGE_SSTATE_CACHE` is overridable by a private variable
in the pipeline schedule settings so that I can optionally delete the cache for a squeaky clean
build.

Ensure that the setting of `SSTATE_CACHE` is appended to the bitbake `conf/local.conf`
file of the build, e.g.

```
.build_image: &build_image
  stage: build
  tags:
    ...
  before_script:
    ...
  script:
    - echo "SSTATE_DIR ?= \"$SSTATE_CACHE\"" >> conf/local.conf
    ...
```

Apply the same pattern to `DL_DIR` if you use it.

Variables you use in the `.yml` file can be overriden by gitlab-ci trigger
or schedule variables. See [Priority of variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#priority-of-variables)